# Efficient boolean masking with Tensorflow SparseTensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, tensorflow2.0

So, I want to mask out entire rows of a `SparseTensor`. This would be easy to do with `tf.boolean_mask`, but there isn't an equivalent for `SparseTensor`s. Currently, something that is possible is for me to just go through all of the indices in `SparseTensor.indices` and filter out all of the ones that aren't a masked row, e.g.:

```py
masked_indices = list(filter(lambda index: masked_rows[index[0]], indices))
```

where masked_rows is a 1D array of whether or not the row at that index is masked.

However, this is really slow, since my SparseTensor is fairly large (it has 90k indices, but will be growing to be significantly larger). It takes quite a few seconds on a single data point, before I even apply `SparseTensor.mask` on the filtered indices. Another flaw of the approach is that it doesn't actually remove the rows, either (although, in my case, a row of all zeros is just as fine).

Is there a better way to mask a SparseTensor by row, or is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def boolean_mask_sparse_1d(sparse_tensor, mask, axis=0):  # mask is assumed to be 1D
    mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask)
    ind = sparse_tensor.indices[:, axis]
    mask_sp = tf.gather(mask, ind)
    new_size = tf.math.count_nonzero(mask)
    new_shape = tf.concat([sparse_tensor.shape[:axis], [new_size],
                           sparse_tensor.shape[axis + 1:]], axis=0)
    new_shape = tf.dtypes.cast(new_shape, tf.int64)
    mask_count = tf.cumsum(tf.dtypes.cast(mask, tf.int64), exclusive=True)
    masked_idx = tf.boolean_mask(sparse_tensor.indices, mask_sp)
    new_idx_axis = tf.gather(mask_count, masked_idx[:, axis])
    new_idx = tf.concat([masked_idx[:, :axis],
                         tf.expand_dims(new_idx_axis, 1),
                         masked_idx[:, axis + 1:]], axis=1)
    new_values = tf.boolean_mask(sparse_tensor.values, mask_sp)
    return tf.SparseTensor(new_idx, new_values, new_shape)

# Test
sp = tf.SparseTensor([[1], [3], [4], [6]], [1, 2, 3, 4], [7])
mask = tf.constant([True, False, True, True, False, False, True])
out = boolean_mask_sparse_1d(sp, mask)
print(out.indices.numpy())
# [[2]
#  [3]]
print(out.values.numpy())
# [2 4]
print(out.shape)
# (4,)
```

Comment: Wait I'm not sure if this is right, as I'm not sure if you want to "delete" (make zero) the masked values in the sparse tensor, or instead remove the values in the sparse tensor as `tf.boolean_mask` actually does. I'm thinking what I posted ("deleting" values) may not be what you were thinking of.

Comment: either way would work, I am just worried about time cost. that solution makes sense to me, let me try it and get back to you

Comment: this looks perfect, it was a big performance jump for me. thanks!

Comment: @porgull I realised my previous solution gave inconsistent results, I fixed it now so it properly works like regular `tf.boolean_mask`.

Comment: ah awesome, I appreciate it @jdehesa